# Perl Module - MIME::Lite::TT::HTML test.html.tt: not found

Tags: html, perl

I am trying to send a mail using MIME::Lite::TT::HTML.

This is my perl script.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use cPanelUserConfig;

 use strict;
 use warnings;
 use MIME::Lite::TT::HTML;

 my %params;

 $params{first_name} = 'Frank';
 $params{last_name}  = 'Wiles';
 $params{amt_due}    = '24.99';

 my %options;
 $options{INCLUDE_PATH} = '.';

 my $msg = MIME::Lite::TT::HTML->new(
            From        =>  'cs@pzr.com',
            To          =>  'xyz@gmail.com',
            Subject     =>  'Your new password',
            Template    => { html => 'test.html.tt' },
            TmplOptions =>  \%options,
            TmplParams  =>  \%params,
 );

 $msg->send;
```

I also created a file named test.html.tt in same directory. Content of that is:

```
     <html>
 <body>

 <strong>Hi [% first_name %]</strong>,

 <p>
 This is to confirm your purchase of $ [% amt_due %].
 </p>

 <p>
 Thank you!
 </p>
 </body>
 </html>
```

But while executing script i am seeing this error:

[Wed Sep 30 11:09:06.557523 2015] [cgi:error] [pid 40187:tid 140571450533632] [client 123.136.217.67:49857] AH01215: file error - test.html.tt: not found: /home//public_html/orders/cgi-bin/testmail.pl

How to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You created `test.html.tt` in same directory as the script, but that's not the directory you told TT to look into. Fix:

```
use FindBin qw( $RealBin );

$options{INCLUDE_PATH} = $RealBin;
```

Comment: Thanks for response. What will be the value of $RealBin?

Comment: The directory of the script, `/home/public_html/orders/cgi-bin`